# Most optimized way to perform calculations on rows of lists of various sizes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list_col': [np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1, np.random.randint(0,10)))[0] for i in range(100000)]})
```

[image]

What would be an optimal way to return the sum of each row? (empty rows = 0)

I read that using .apply is usually discouraged in pandas

```
df.list_col.apply(sum)
```

[image]

However, when trying to make proper use of vectorized calculations, I was only able to come up with the following:

```
np.nansum(pd.DataFrame(df.list_col.values.tolist()).values, axis=1)
```

which turned out to be slower:
[image]

**So what would be a proper way to use numpy's vectorized calculations on an array of lists of varying sizes?**

Comment: `df["list_col"].map(sum)` is slightly faster than both for me.

Comment: @TobyPetty interesting, any explanation why map would be faster than apply?

Comment: Just "Optimized". you cannot be "more" or "less" optimized :)

Comment: Lists or arrays of varying length cannot be 'vectorized'.  The fast `numpy` code works with numeric arrays with rectangular shape.  Your lists cannot be combined into one 2d integer array.

Comment: You have a Series of lists, I’m not sure what you expect from NumPy. Please clarify things.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us more context for your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the speed `list` with `map` is little faster than others

```
%timeit df.list_col.apply(sum)
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
%timeit np.nansum(pd.DataFrame(df.list_col.values.tolist()).values, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 169 ms per loop
%timeit list(map(sum,df.list_col.tolist()))
10 loops, best of 3: 93.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: well done, this is indeed a little faster than other approaches

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is pretty optimized, you can save a few milliseconds

```
%timeit df['list_col'].map(sum)
162 ms ± 5.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit df['list_col'].apply(sum)
156 ms ± 747 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit df['list_col'].map(np.sum)
306 ms ± 3.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I prefer to use `map` when it's a `series` operation since `apply` is usually used for `dataframes`.